# Combining many 3D numpy arrays into one, from shape from (3, 2, 1) to (3, 2, 4)

Tags: python, numpy

I know that this has probably been asked before, but in all of the questions i am looking, they are talking about a different type of reshaping.

Let's say that we have the following numpy arrays:

```
data1 = np.array([[[12], [13]], [[14], [15]], [[16], [17]]])
data2 = np.array([[[22], [23]], [[24], [25]], [[26], [27]]])
data3 = np.array([[[32], [33]], [[34], [35]], [[36], [37]]])
data4 = np.array([[[42], [43]], [[44], [45]], [[46], [47]]])
```

with a shape of `(3, 2, 1)`

How can we combine these four arrays so we can get the following shape `(3, 2, 4)`

```
result = np.array([[[12, 22, 32, 42], [13, 23, 33, 43]], [[14, 24, 34, 44], [15, 25, 35, 45]], [[16, 26, 36, 46], [17, 27, 36, 47]]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate):

```
np.concatenate((data1, data2, data3, data4), axis=2)
```